# The method println(double) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)

Tags: java, string, variables, double

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoviePrices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        double adult = 10.50;
        double child = 7.50;
        System.out.println("How many adult tickets?");
        int fnum = user.nextInt();

        double aprice = fnum * adult;
        System.out.println("The cost of your movie tickets before is ", aprice);

    }
}
```

I am very new  to coding and this is a project of mine for school. I am trying to print the variable aprice within that string but I am getting the error in the heading.

Comment: Use String concatenation with the `+` operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
System.out.println("The cost of your movie tickets before is ", aprice);
```

Do this:

```
System.out.println("The cost of your movie tickets before is " + aprice);
```

This is called "concatenation". Read [this Java trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) for more info.

**Edit:** You could also use formatting via `PrintStream.printf`. For example:

```
double aprice = 4.0 / 3.0;
System.out.printf("The cost of your movie tickets before is %f\n", aprice);
```

Prints:

> The cost of your movie tickets before is 1.333333

You could even do something like this:

```
double aprice = 4.0 / 3.0;
System.out.printf("The cost of your movie tickets before is $%.2f\n", aprice);
```

This will print:

> The cost of your movie tickets before is $1.33

The `%.2f` can be read as "format (the `%`) as a number (the `f`) with 2 decimal places (the `.2`)." The `$` in front of the `%` is just for show, btw, it's not part of the format string other than saying "put a $ here". You can find the formatting specs in the [`Formatter` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for

```
System.out.println("The cost of your movie tickets before is " + aprice);
```

`+` concatenates Strings. `,` separates method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
System.out.println("The cost of your movie tickets before is " + aprice);
```

And you can also do that:

```
System.out.printf("The cost of your movie tickets before is %f\n", aprice);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
System.out.println("The cost of your movie tickets before is " + aprice);
```

The reason is that if you put in a coma, you are sending two different parameters. If you use the line above, you add the double onto your string, and then it sends the parameters as a String rather than a String and a double.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you use `,` instead of `+`  i.e:

use this one:

```
System.out.println ("x value" +x);
```

instead of

```
System.out.println ("x value", +x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found the answer yet, but I understood that you should write like this:

```java
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("My name is = {0}, My FirstLetter Name is {1}, Myage is = {2}",Myname,myfirstl,d));
```