# Receiving error for profit calculator?

Tags: java

Still new to Java and I am tasked with making a profit calculator for a paper boy, however I received this error:

```
Enter the number of daily papers delivered: 50
Enter the number of Sunday papers delivered: 35
The amount collected for daily papers was: Exception in thread "main" java.util
IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at lab2b_MontelWhite.main(lab2b_MontelWhite.java:24)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Paper Boy's Wages Calculator

import java.util.Scanner;
public abstract class lab2b
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
        int x;
        int y;
        int result;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of daily papers delivered: ");
        x = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of Sunday papers delivered: ");
        y = input.nextInt();
        double dailyResult = x * .3;

        System.out.printf("The amount collected for daily papers was: %d\n",
        dailyResult);
        int SundayResult = y * 1;

        System.out.printf("The amount collected for Sunday papers was: %d\n", 

        SundayResult);
        double totalResult = dailyResult + SundayResult;

        System.out.printf("The total amount of money collected was: %d\n",    

        totalResult);
        double ProfitResult = (SundayResult + dailyResult)/2;

        System.out.printf("The paper boy's profit is: %d\n", ProfitResult);
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have added doubles, I have changed the name of the "results". I'm just not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `%d` is for integers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) javadocs to see all of the data type format letters.

From that page, `%d` formats the numbers as a "decimal integer". This is probably what confused you. This really means "base-10 integer", like using (30)<sub>10</sub> to represent the binary number (11110)<sub>2</sub>. The important thing to look at in the conversion types is the argument category. "Integral" in that column means whole-number data types without fractional parts, like `int`, `long`, and `BigInteger`. "Floating point", on the other hand, means *with* a fractional part, like `double`, `float`, and `BigDecimal`. In your case, you want `%f`.

You could also specify a precision as well, which is the number of digits shown in the fractional part of the number. Since you're working with money, I'll show an example using USD:

```
System.out.printf("The amount collected for Sunday papers was: $%.2f\n",
    SundayResult);
```

Which would print something like:

```
The amount collected for Sunday papers was: $65.33
```

Instead of:

```
The amount collected for Sunday papers was: $65.333333333
```

Resources:

- [`Formatter` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [Java Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)
- [Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260337/)

Comment: I hate that I can only select one answer. Both were very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

`%d` is a decimal integer. Use `%f` for doubles.

You can read about the format string syntax in the documentation of [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 3):

Should be-

```
System.out.printf("The amount collected for daily papers was: %f\n", dailyResult);
System.out.printf("The total amount of money collected was: %f\n",  totalResult);
System.out.printf("The paper boy's profit is: %f\n", ProfitResult);
```

Since %f for doubles and %d for integers. If you want to have two decimal points, you can do-

```
String.format("%.2f", ProfitResult);
```

**[Oracle tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)**